# .htaccess files being ignored by Apache2 on Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, apache2, webserver, virtualhost, mod-rewrite

My wordpress install is ignoring my .htaccess file. I am running Lubuntu 18.04 locally with Apache2. The root directory for localhost is at `/var/www/html` and my wordpress project is in that folder under `/wptest2`

**Diagnosing the problem**

- The pretty urls on my local install are all broken. Ugly urls work fine though.
- I put a breaking change towards the top of the .htaccess file and it didn't cause a 500 internal server error, it just caused a `not found` or loaded the page depending on if I enabled pretty or ugly urls.

**Things I have tried**

**Enabling mod rewrite**

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
$ systemctl restart apache2
$
```

[image]

rewrite module appears enabled. Problem is not fixed however.

**Allowing overrides to the virtual hosts file**

```
owner@G700:/var/www/html$ apache2ctl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
<continues ...>

$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

[image]

```
$ systemctl restart apache2
$
```

Pretty urls are still broken and the intentional breaking line in .htaccess seems to be ignored.

What else could be the issue? These are the contents of my .htaccess file at: `/var/www/html/wptest2`

```
this line should cause a 500 internal server error

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

**Update**

Inside folder /var/log/apache2, `error.log` doesn't show anything related. I see this in `access.log`:

```
::1 - - [20/Sep/2019:00:45:58 +0700] "GET /icons/text.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 512 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gec$
::1 - - [20/Sep/2019:00:45:58 +0700] "GET /icons/unknown.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 528 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like $
::1 - - [20/Sep/2019:00:46:05 +0700] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 200 26906 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809$
::1 - - [20/Sep/2019:01:04:48 +0700] "GET /wptest2/category/uncategorized/ HTTP/1.1" 404 488 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Ge$
::1 - - [20/Sep/2019:01:04:50 +0700] "GET /wptest2/category/uncategorized/ HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Ge$
::1 - - [20/Sep/2019:01:04:51 +0700] "GET /wptest2/category/uncategorized/ HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Ge$
::1 - - [20/Sep/2019:01:04:52 +0700] "GET /wptest2/category/uncategorized/ HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Ge$
::1 - - [20/Sep/2019:01:04:54 +0700] "GET /wptest2/category/uncategorized/ HTTP/1.1" 404 487 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Ge$
```

That is the url I was testing on. In the browser it is broken, showing this:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

I have tested a request using curl and it still shows not found:

```
owner@G700:/var/www/html$ curl -I http://localhost/wptest2/category/uncategorized
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 19 Sep 2019 19:52:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Browsers tend to cache things.  Have you tried doing `curl -I http://website/wptest2/category/uncategorized` to see if it does actually error out?  Because Browsers are notorious for not working properly with testing things

Comment: I have just tried it but it also shows `404 not found`

Comment: is there any other `.htaccess` in the root `/var/www/html`? If so try to move/rename it

Comment: Ok, I  have renamed the one in that folder to `old .htaccess`. the curl command still shows 404 not found though